# Variable not initialized and hides in field

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, initialization

I'm fairly new to java, so I don't understand why i'm getting an initialization error. In the code my integer "Memes" is saying that it might not have been initialized and that a local variable hides in field.

```
 private void totalUpdate(int yes){


     if (yes==1){
             int CompBot = Integer.parseInt(lblbotComp.getText());
     int CompTop = Integer.parseInt(lbltopComp.getText());
     int CompMid = Integer.parseInt(lblmidComp.getText());

                int Memes = Memes + CompBot + CompTop + CompMid;
          lbltotalComp.setText("Computer has earned "+ Memes +" points in total");
}
    }
 private void pointUpdate(int points){
     pointsUser = pointsUser + points ;
     lbluserPointsEst.setText (""+pointsUser+"");
 }

 private void computerPointUpdate(int pointComp){
     pointsComputer = pointsComputer + pointComp ;
     lblcompPointsEst.setText (""+pointsComputer+"");
 }

 private int play(int points){
int score;
int randomScore = (int)((100 -1 +1)*Math.random() +1);
 if (randomScore < points){
     score = points;
     }
    else{
   score = 100;
    }

return score;
 }

 private int playComp(int pointsComp){
int score;
int randomScore = (int)((100 -1 +1)*Math.random() +1);
 if (randomScore < pointsComp){
     score = pointsComp;
     }
    else{
   score = 100;
    }

  return score;
 }

        private int Memes = 0;
        private final Timer messageTimer;
        private int pointsComputer = 0;
        private int pointsUser = 0;
        private int count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive this warning because you have `private int Memes` in your class definition, as well as a declared variable `int Memes` in `totalUpdate()`.

How to fix it depends on what you want:

If you want `totalUpdate()` to update the value of `Memes` in your object, leave out `int` in the line in question like this:

`Memes = Memes + CompBot + CompTop + CompMid;`

If you want to declare a new local variable, it is better to give it a different name:

`int localMemes = Memes + CompBot + CompTop + CompMid;`

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
int Memes = Memes + CompBot + CompTop + CompMid;
```

Java treats this as a declaration of a new variable, which hides field

```
private int Memes = 0;
```

It looks like you wanted to initialize `Memes` which is the field. In order to do that, drop `int` in front of the assignment:

```
Memes = Memes + CompBot + CompTop + CompMid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably in this line:

```
int Memes = Memes + CompBot + CompTop + CompMid;
```

The variable "Memes" can be either the one defined in the method totalUpdate() or the object's attribute. So the parser gets confused.

Try to change the variable's name to something like localMemes or such.

Also since you're new in Java I suggest reading this article on Naming Conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare "Memes" at the field level:

```
int Memes = 0; //for example
```

then

```
Memes += CompBot + CompTop + CompMid;
```

also lower case names for ints/objects helps readability from class names.

```
memes += compBot + compTop + compMid;
```